# How to skip the first n rows in a MySQL database with a Java program?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a problem. I am writing a java application which shall move some files. Because of performance issues the user can select the amount of files that shall be moved. If the file is moved, my database shall be updated with the new paths. I've already coded that but my problem now is that it just works for the first, for example, 10 files. Then the application terminates.

So until now everything works as expected. Now I want to start the application again and it shall move 10 files again. Now the problem is that it starts again at the top of the database and tries to move the first 10 files, which have been already moved in the first run of my application. So how can I tell my program that it shall skip the first 10(n) files?

I had the idea of generating a new column to the database with ones and zeros. And every file that has been moved gets a 1 and its set by default to zero. Then the program checks if there is a one or a zero and if there is a one then it just continues with the next row. But I didn't find a way on how to create a column in a database with java. The next problem is that this column shall be deleted after the run of the application.

I tried to write a procedure and I found this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Alter_Table()
BEGIN
  DECLARE _count INT;
    SET _count =( SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'test_cm_documents' AND
                    COLUMN_NAME='subscribe_all');
  IF _count = 0 THEN
    ALTER TABLE test_cm_documents
    ADD COLUMN subscribe_all TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
        ADD COLUMN subscribe_category varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL;
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It worked if I pasted it into the MySQL command line but it did not worked when I tried to execute it with a Java program. I also tried to save that as a *.sql file but I can't execute it from my Java program.

I have two Java Programs with which I tried to solve my Problems but I got several errors.

```
import java.io.*;

public class CmdExec {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "mysql -u myuser -p xxxx -d cm_database -h 3306 -f C://Users//****//Desktop//procedure.sql");
        BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        input.close();
    }catch(Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

ERRORS:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysql": CreateProcess error=2, 
Das 
  System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
      at CmdExec.main(CmdExec.java:8)
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann 
 die angegebene Datei nicht finden
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

Second Java program:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class startProcedure {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cm_database?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&SSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC",
            "myuser","xxxx");
            
            Statement delimiter = conn.createStatement();){
        
            String delimiterStr = 
                    "CREATE PROCEDURE Alter_Table() "
                    + " BEGIN "
                    + " DECLARE _count INT; "
                    + " SET _count =( SELECT COUNT(*) "
                                   + " FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS "
                                   + " WHERE TABLE_NAME='test_cm_documents' AND "
                                          + " COLUMN_NAME='subscribe_all'); "
                    + " IF _count = 0 THEN "
                        + " ALTER TABLE test_cm_documents"
                           + " ADD COLUMN subscribe_all TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,"
                           + " ADD COLUMN subscribe_category varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL "
                           + " END IF; "
                    + " END; "
                    ;
            
            delimiter.executeUpdate(delimiterStr);
    }catch(SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
}
 
    }
```

I get following error: You have an error in your SQL Statement.

Maybe someone can help me, because I am quite new to the topic. Excellent will be an application which will just skip n rows. I thinks this will be the most easy solution.

Comment: You need to point out exactly where the problem(s) is in your code.  We can't easily look at this question and guess what is broken.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My big problem is that I don't find a way how to skip n rows in a database with a java program.

Comment: Why are you using a db procedure to move files anyway? Wouldn't a proper plain SQL query be enough? Skipping n rows could normally done via some form of offset but that's a strange design. I'd mark the rows that have been handled already and ignore them in the next run (filter them).

Comment: Skip rows where?  In a file?  In a database table?  Something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In a database table. So I have a database with a table with ca. 100000 rows. In the table there are the paths of 100.000 files and those 100.000 shall be moved. So the paths shall be changed to the new path. And I want to move first 1000 files and then another 1000 and not 100.000 at once. So the user can give the Program an amount of the files that shall be moved. And for example the user says that 1000 files shall be moved. And then the program move 1000 files and then terminates. Then the program shall move 1000 files again, but not the first 1000 because they had been moved

Comment: just write raw query `select * from table_name limit x offset y;` -- to skip y rows

Comment: @Thomas Jeah but I have 100.000 files so I need an application which marks the rows and ignores them. But I cant figure out a way how to let that happen automatically.

Comment: @sovannarithcheav Thanks a lot, that helped me. I will now try to use this query in java with ````executeQuery();````

Comment: @DavidKrell Happy to know that :)

Comment: @sovannarithcheav If you want to you can write an answer and then I can give it a vote up and can mark it as the answer that solved my problem. Then others can have a solution if they have the same problem and you will gain some reputation points. (;

Comment: @sovannarithcheav I have a new question. How do I combine ````select * from table_name limit x offset y```` with  ````where document_path IS NOT NULL```` ?

Comment: @DavidKrell yes you can, use like this `select * from table_name where document_path IS NOT NULL limit x offset y `

Comment: "I need an application which marks the rows and ignores them." - Well that's exactly what I mean. You'd basically update the rows to mark those that have been moved already and select only those that havent, e.g. something like `UPDATE test_cm_documents SET path = "some_new_path"` and ignoring would be something like `SELECT * FROM test_cm_documents WHERE path like '/old/base/path/%'` - that way you'd only select documents whose path is still the old one (assuming you can easily distinguish between "old" and "new" paths).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OFFSET is what you are looking for :

`select * from table_name limit x offset y;` -- to skip y rows

Or use LIMIT with two parameters. For example, to return 30 rows with first 10 rows skipped (will return 11 to 40), use:

`select * from table_name limit 10, 30;`

Answer (score -2):

Use Cte query to skip first 10(n) files and get recent save same row.
for example

UID     GID   MID
   1        1      1
   2        1      2
   3        1      2
   4        1      2
   5        2      1
   6        2      2
   7        2      2
   8        2      3
   9        2      4

```
with Demo as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by GID, MID order by UID) as ROWNUMBER  from Table1
)
```

cte create a table

```
UID     GID   MID   ROWNUMBER
1        1      1      1
2        1      2      1
3        1      2      2
4        1      2      3 
5        2      1      1
6        2      2      1
7        2      2      2
8        2      3      5
9        2      4      4

select  * from Demo ROWNUMBER  = 1
```